# Why is a sample defined as a set of observable random variables?

Tags: random-variables, statistical-inference, sampling-theory

I have learned that a Random variable is a mapping from sample space to a real number and is denoted as X, Y ,Z for different functions (random variables). Say, in the case of rolling two dice, X can be defined as random variable that gives the probability of the sum of the face value upon rolling and Y another random variable that gives the probability of the face value being even.

Okay and now as I move on from probability to statistics I see the "Random variables" in the definition of a sample and there it has been denoted as X1, X2, X3, with subscripts denoting the random variable. I am totally confused with the notation and does X1,X2,X3....Xn imply *n* different random variables ?  Can somebody interpret the meaning of the ideology.

Source : - the textbook definition of a sample given in the textbook "Mathematical Statistics with Applications" by Ramachandran:

> "A sample is a set of observable random variables X1,X2...,Xn. The number n is called the sample size."

Comment: Which part is confusing to you, the subscripts? For an example, imagine that you roll $n$ dice, and that each of the $X_i$ is the value of a particular die (the face that is up on that roll).

Comment: Also, in your earlier examples, what does it mean that $Y$ is a random variable that "gives the probability of the face value being even"?  Do you mean that $Y$ is defined to be $1$ if the value of the roll is even and $0$ if the value of the roll is odd?

Comment: yes Y takes the value 0 and 1, for  odd and  even
and X takes the values 2,3,4,5,6.......12

Comment: both are two different random variable

Comment: So, for example, if you rolled a die $n$ times, you could define $Y_i$ to be $1$ if the $i^\text{th}$ roll was even, and $0$ if it was odd. That would give you $n$ random variables. In this case, the random variables are all independent and identically distributed.

Comment: Does my comment clear things up, or is there something that is still unclear? They are $n$ different random variables.  If it's still unclear, can you explain what part is unclear?

Comment: There are also related questions on this site https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324984/terminology-regarding-random-sample and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62967/samples-and-random-variables

Comment: oh thank you i'll look into it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133903/discussion-between-charles-and-joe).

Comment: so the subscript indicates the number of trials. is it.

Comment: The subscript is basically a name for the random variable.  If each of your random variables came from a different trial, then you can name them so that the subscript corresponds to the trial. If you roll 5 dice all at the same time, and name the variables $X_1, \ldots, X_5$, then the subscript indicates which die the variable corresponds to. You could have any two random variables, that have nothing to do with each other, and decide to name one of them $X_1$ and the other $X_2$. However, often we are interested in simple random samples for which all of the random variables are i.i.d.